# Code is not working with dynamically added element

Tags: jquery

I am using following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text_message").autosize();
}
```

for [autosizing](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) the text box.
My problem is this is not working for dynamically added text boxes.
How to resolve this?

Comment: `autosize.update` seems to be the way to do it looking at the docs

Comment: Can you show the code how are you adding that .text_message to the DOM? You can do it after adding the new object, but I can't answer without seeing the code.

Comment: You need to initialize the plugin for those dynamic elements after they are created

Answer (score 1):

Because the script runs on `$(document).ready` it will only work for elements that exist when your page loads.

You need to use something like the `on` method on the parent so that elements added after are also affected.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Another good reference: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $(".text_message").autosize();
});
```